# Template tag for joining two words in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

how to write a template tag that joins two words which is given as input, the input may or may not be template variables, and out put it as string or a template variable

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Comment: I can't imagine why you even need a template tag for displaying two words next to each other.

Comment: Why dont you pass these words already joined in your view to the template?

Comment: Just so you know this is more complicated than you might imagine. Because it sounds like you want to be able to output something like `{% join foo bar %}` and have it display `foo bar` if both are strings but `foo eggs` if `bar` happens to be a variable in the context. It's doable but complicated, and generally if you're using a complicated solution to solve a non-complicated problem you might not have the right solution. Maybe it would be better to say exactly what you're trying to do, with example.s

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want.

Create a folder called *templatetags* in your app folder. Add a **init**.py file and a file called something like *yourapp_extras.py* with a content like:

```
def joinWords(word1, word2):
    return '%s%s' % (word1, word2)
register.filter('joinWords', joinWords)
```

Put

```
{% load yourapp_extras %}
```

at the top of your template and use it like

```
{{ "word1"|joinWords:"word2" }}
```

Comment: @user1144808 Just so you know, `{{ word1 }}{{ word2 }}` will work just  as well as @xeor 's solution.

Comment: Very true, however, that was not the original question. The user asking the question might have all kinda reasons to ask it. Maybe he needed something like this for a bigger templatetag. Examples are always a good thing, even tough in this case its a little overkill :)